# SIGABRT C++, throwing Exceptions

Tags: c++, sigabrt

Sorry if the post is newbish, I'm mostly a math-guy.

I'm writing a little C++ command line tool for one of my classes on Operations Research.

I have something like:

```
try {
   if( *some condition* ) {
      throw MY_ENUM;
   }
   ...
}
catch (int e) {
   if (e == MY_ENUM) {
      // output some diagnostics and exit
   }
   ...
}
```

But I keep getting a SIGABRT being thrown instead of MY_ENUM. I know its something elementary I'm forgetting, but can't pin it down. Thanks

Comment: If `MY_EMUM` is an enum, you need to catch the enum type, rather than `int`.

Comment: It could be a library call like for example malloc(), they use SIGABRT. Can you add more code?

Comment: Get a core dump and analyze it, or use a debugger.

Comment: @Mankarse catching `int` won't catch enums? I never knew that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting this answer so this stops showing up as unanswered. @Mankarse answered this correctly and promptly as a comment, so please accept their answer instead of mine if they post one.

---

The exception here isn't being caught because the object being thrown is of some enum type, and the code above catches `int`s.

To catch the enum value thrown, use `catch (MyEnumType e) { if (e == MY_ENUM) ... }` instead

Comment: Ya it's working now. Seems odd catching an `int` wouldn't default to catching enumerated types. Seems along the same paradigm as catching some exception class also catches classes derived from said class..